# Show that a symmetric matrix $A$ is positive definite given $A_{ij}$

Tags: matrices, summation, numerical-linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

I have a symmetric matrix $A$ of size $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ that I want to show is positive definite,

$$
A_{ij} = 
     \begin{cases}
       0 &\quad\text{if } i+j \text{ odd}\\
       \frac{2}{i+j+1} &\quad\text{if } i+j \text{ even}\\
     \end{cases}.
$$

I know that $A$ is positive definite $\iff$ $\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x}>0$ for all $\mathbf{x} \neq 0$.

I have attempted to solve this using summations:

$$
\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x} = \sum^n_{i=0}x_i\sum^n_{j=0}A_{i,j}x_j .
$$

However when I try to simplify this nothing seems to quite work, eg.

$$
\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x} = \sum^n_{i=0}x_i\sum^{n/2}_{j=0}A_{i,2j}x_{2j} = \sum^n_{i=0}x_i\sum^{n/2}_{j=0}\frac{2}{i+2j+1}x_{2j} ,
$$
clearly this is not true.

I'd really appreciate a nudge in the correct direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you evaluate $\int_{-1}^1 x^i x^j dx$?

Comment: @kimchilover $A_{i,j} = \int^1_{-1}x^ix^jdx$ however I am unsure how writing it in that form will help

Comment: It exhibits your matrix as a [Gram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) matrix.  You need to do a tiny bit more, to show it is actually positive definite, as opposed to merely p.s.d..

Comment: @kimchilover that's genius, thank you!